# How to rearrange columns when you don't know their initial positions (UNIX, BASH)

Tags: bash, unix, csv

I'm having an issue to rearrange columns of a csv file (separator ";").
I know where the columns should be, but not where they are in the first place.

Example of file:

> **first_name** ; **age** ; **vehicle**
> Jacques ; 30 ; Suzuki

Another example of file:

> **vehicle** ; *notImportantColumn1* ; **age** ; **first_name** ; *notImportantColumns2*
> Suzuki; *notImportantData1* ; 30 ; Jacques ; *notImportantData2*

--> And I want to rearrange the csv file, so I have :

> **age** ; **first_name** ; **vehicle** ; *allNotImportantColumns*
> 30 ; Jacques ; Suzuki; *allNotImportantData*

I've tried to retrieve the position of the desired columns in variables like so

```
variable_age=$(awk -F ';' 'NR==1{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "age") print i }' file.csv)  
...
```

and then rearrange them by using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"; OFS=";"} {print $variable_age, ... }' file.csv
```

But, as I feared it, "$variable_age" isn't a proper argument

Someone has an idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is very easy. Running

```
mlr --csv --fs ";" reorder -f age,first_name,vehicle ./input.csv >./output.csv
```

you will have

```
+-----+------------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
| age | first_name | vehicle | notImportantColumn1 | notImportantColumns2 |
+-----+------------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
| 30  | Jacques    | Suzuki  |  notImportantData1  | notImportantData2    |
+-----+------------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: really simple, thanks Miller